# Saving an Object into Database

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I'm trying to save and load an Object into a database Field of type BLOB.
Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Example:

Saving an instance of `vk.class.Offer.cls` to DB-Table `OfferHead`
and loading `objOffer` of type `vk.class.Offer.cls` from DB-Table `OfferHead`.

I'm trying the following code:

```
   DEFINE VARIABLE objAngebot AS CLASS vk.class.Angebot NO-UNDO.
   DEFINE VARIABLE oObj       as MemPTR                 NO-UNDO.

   DEFINE BUFFER bAngKopf FOR AngKopf.

   COPY-LOB  bAngKopf.ank_ObjHandle TO oObj.
   objAngebot = CAST(oObj, vk.class.Angebot).
```

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is *serialize*, and there is information for Progress OpenEdge in [Serializing classes to binary and JSON formats](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/gspub/serializing-classes-to-binary-and-json-formats.html).

Comment: What are you trying that isn’t working?  Are there error messages or other helpful clues regarding what is going wrong with those attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by writing the Object to a file and rereading it back into DB.

```
COPY-LOB FROM bAngPos.anp_ObjHandle TO FILE cPfadPos.
  objInputStream = NEW Progress.IO.FileInputStream(cPfadPos).
  objSerializer = NEW Progress.IO.BinarySerializer().
  objAngebotPos = CAST(objSerializer:Deserialize(objInputStream), vk.class.AngebotPos) NO-ERROR.
  objInputStream:Close().
  OS-DELETE VALUE(cPfadPos).
```